# Json Deserialization to a class

Tags: c#, json, deserialization

I have dynamic json result and i want to create an object for that json string. After that i will fill that object with the deserialized object. Here is the json string:

```
[{"_34":{
   "Id":"34",
   "Z":["42b23718-bbb8-416e-9241-538ff54c28c9","c25ef97a-89a5-4ed7-89c7-9c6a17c2413b"],
   "C":[]
   }
}]
```

How does the object look like? Or how can i deserialize this string to a class.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [JavaScriptSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx) which available out of the box or [json.net](http://json.codeplex.com/) if you prefer something open source.

Based on [Darin Dimitrov's sample](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9394924/226277), here's how you'd do with json.net:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
   class Program
   {
          static void Main(string[] args)
          {
              string json = "[{\"_34\":{ \"Id\":\"34\", \"Z\":[\"42b23718-bbb8-416e-9241-538ff54c28c9\",\"c25ef97a-89a5-4ed7-89c7-9c6a17c2413b\"], \"C\":[] } }]";
              var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, Result>[]>(json);
              Console.WriteLine(result[0]["_34"].Z[1]);
           }
   }

   public class Result
   {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string[] Z { get; set; }
        public string[] C { get; set; }
   }
}
```

Comment: Json.NET is not only open source, but also a *lot* faster than the JSS in the .NET Framework and more efficient in memory usage. This is a very good suggestion.

Comment: Well how can i get the Result object in for loop? Because in that json array there can be more than one "_34" object. I also should be able to get the Result object directly.

Comment: Here's [a sample](https://gist.github.com/1885213) for the loop but please ask a new question if you'd need further help about the code.

Comment: Thanks, i also want to serialize it to the result object, is there an example for it?

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;

public class Result
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string[] Z { get; set; }
    public string[] C { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var json = @"[{""_34"": {""Id"": ""34"",""Z"": [""42b23718-bbb8-416e-9241-538ff54c28c9"",""c25ef97a-89a5-4ed7-89c7-9c6a17c2413b""],""C"": []}}]";
        var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        var result = serializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, Result>[]>(json);
        Console.WriteLine(result[0]["_34"].Z[1]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Target class**

```
public class Target
{
    public string Id;
    public List<string> Z;
    public List<string> C;
}
```

**Deserialization**

```
var ser = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var obj = ser.Deserialize<Target>(json);
```

Comment: This won't work with the JSON string shown by the OP. His JSON string is an array whereas you are trying to deserialize to a single type Target.

Answer (score -2):

Wrap your string in eval function:

```
var myObject = eval('(' + myJSONtext + ')');
```

Comment: In which namespace is the `eval` function defined?

Comment: Eval is a global function in javascript. http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_eval.asp