# Painless JSON deserialization in C# using JSON.NET

Tags: c#, javascript, json

What is the most painless way to deserialize this JSON in C# using JSON.NET?

```
{
"serNo":{
            "A4":{
                    "vol":[["0","100","0,1"],["0","n","0"]],
                    "fix":"900"
                    },
            "A3":{
                    "vol":[["0","200","0,5"],["0","n","0"]],
                    "fix":"700"
                    }
        }
}
```

To create a separate class or as collection?

EDIT: There will be multiple "serNo" properties.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my opinion, the most painless way to deserialize any JSON is to use the JSON.NET library. See also http://json.codeplex.com.

**EDIT:** Also see this other question on Stack Overflow: [How to deserialize with JSON.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6398553/how-to-deserialize-with-json-net)

Comment: I'm already using that lib, but I'm not sure how to deserialize this one. It's a bit complex...for me at least.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the **build in** lightweight [**JavaScriptSerializer**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx). **No attributes** are required on the classes you want to serialize/deserialize.

It can also handle **anonymous types**.

Serialization:

```
var serializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
var objectAsJsonString = serializer.Serialize(objectToSerialize);
```

Deserialization:

```
var serializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
SomeClass deserializedObject = serializer.Deserialize<SomeClass>(objectToDeserialize);
```

Here is the link to an earlier related question/answer: 
[Error converting JSON to .Net object in asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2668626/error-converting-json-to-net-object-in-asp-net/2669227#2669227)

Answer (score 1):

OK, I solved the problem with JSON.NET by creating this class:

> ```
> class Counter
> {
>    public double[][] vol { get; set; }
>
>    public double fix { get; set; }
> }
> ```

and

deserialized JSON with this expression:

```
Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, Counter>> counters = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, Counter>>>(arg.Args[7]);
```

Where arg.Args[7] is JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the C# section at [json.org](http://json.org/)

Answer (score 0):

See Darin's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9394924/253793).

I think you easily modify provided source code to match your needs. This is built-in to the .NET framework (`System.Web.Script.Serialization`), so there are no external dependencies.

Comment: I don't require tool, but the way to deserialize given example using JSON.NET.

Comment: @dakt Okay, please update your question that you want solve the problem using JSON.NET. Thanks